# AngularJS and CSS: how to display only X number of items per row

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

So I am wondering how can I display only 3 items per row in my AngularJS ng-repeat div. I am not using bootstrap - I only use ionic framework.

Any help will be great!

Thanks,
uksz

Here is my code sample:

```
<div users><{{users}}</div></div>
```

and my directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users" id="user-picture">
    <img ng-src="{{user.cachedUserProfile.picture.data.url}}">{{user}}</div>
    <label class="attending-name"> {{user.displayName}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: 3 items per row or 3 rows?

Comment: you need to show us your code...

Comment: i have done that using a directive.. though for bootstrap.. it does one simple thing `var size = 12/items-per-row; className='col-md-'+size` and then use `class={{className}}` in html

Comment: this question has been answered already.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643361/ngrepeat-limiting-number-of-displayed-results][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643361/ngrepeat-limiting-number-of-displayed-results

Comment: @entre : your solution is linked to bootStrap CSS component

Comment: Ionic use flexbox css style. If you are triying to make x-rows with a maximum of 3 elements you can use flex-wrap property and a ng-repeat inside a div with col-33 class. The css engine go to place the next div down automatically.