# how make ng repeat run only 10 times

Tags: angularjs

I have to modify the UI for a Leshan Client. Currently the way it is setup, it displays every instance of the client in the browser. How do i make it display only 10 clients, although I will be still creating hundreds of them? I tried to modify the code below for ng repeat and ng click but the only thing that changes is that I stop displaying any of the clients.

```
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="client in clients" ng-click="showClient(client)">
            <td><a ng-href="#/clients/{{client.endpoint}}"> <strong>{{client.endpoint}}</strong></a> </td>
            <td>{{client.registrationId}}</td>
            <td>{{client.registrationDate | date:'medium'}}</td>
            <td>{{client.lastUpdate | date:'medium'}}</td>
            <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" tooltip-html-unsafe="{{clientTooltip(client)}}"></i></td>
            <td><span ng-class="{hidden: client.secure == false}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" tooltip-html-unsafe="Communication over DTLS"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: try `limitTo` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643361/ngrepeat-limiting-number-of-displayed-results

Comment: It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="client in clients | limitTo:10" ng-click="showClient(client)">
            <td><a ng-href="#/clients/{{client.endpoint}}"> <strong>{{client.endpoint}}</strong></a> </td>
            <td>{{client.registrationId}}</td>
            <td>{{client.registrationDate | date:'medium'}}</td>
            <td>{{client.lastUpdate | date:'medium'}}</td>
            <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" tooltip-html-unsafe="{{clientTooltip(client)}}"></i></td>
            <td><span ng-class="{hidden: client.secure == false}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" tooltip-html-unsafe="Communication over DTLS"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

use **ng-if**

```
<div ng-repeat="i in values">
    <div ng-if="i < 3">Hello</div>
</div>
```

[working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/MwXDUATbJrc8DlXbtRzm?p=preview)

or use an auxiliar variable just to display the results you want